# Rails Edit Action Couldn't Find "Model" with ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, routes

I've been working on various Rails apps for a while now, but just today decided to work on a quick project/task app for fun.

I am able to create Projects and tasks, assign users, and a due date.  I'm using a member route to nest the tasks for each project and can create a new task without a problem.  My issue comes to when I'm trying to edit the task from the tasks index view.  I think I have my instance variables wrong in the tasks controller.  It raises an exception: Couldn't find Project with id=12 (where 12 is supposed to be the project id, which doesn't exist) and redirects to a url of: http://todoapp.dev/projects/12/tasks/12/edit where 12 is really the actual task id.

Here's what my code looks like

routes.rb

```
Todoapp::Application.routes.draw do



  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :users

resources :projects do
  member do
  resources :tasks
end
end
root :to => "projects#index"
end
```

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :project_name, :user_id, :due_date
  has_many :tasks
  belongs_to :user
end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :completed, :detail, :due_date, :user_id, :project_id
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :user
end
```

projects_controller.rb

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.order('due_date ASC')
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    if @project.save
        redirect_to projects_path, notice: "Project #{@project.project_name} was successfully created.".html_safe
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        redirect_to projects_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
        redirect_to tasks_path, notice: "Task #{@task.detail} was successfully created.".html_safe
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        redirect_to tasks_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

tasks/index.html.erb

```
<h2><%= @project.project_name %> tasks</h2>

<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
<%= t.detail %> - <%= t.user.full_name %> - <%= t.due_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%y") %> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(t), class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %></br>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Add task", new_task_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %>
```

tasks/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for(@task, :html => { :class => "well"}) do |f|  %>

  <%= f.label 'detail'%>
  <%= f.text_field :detail, :placeholder => 'Buy tool'%>
  <%= f.label 'Assigned To'%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name)%>
  <%= f.label :due_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :due_date %>
   <%= f.button "Add Task", class: 'btn btn-info btn-mini', data: {disable_with: "Adding Task"} %> 

<% end %>
```

tasks/edit.html.erb

```
Edit Task
<%= render 'form' %>
```

I think I'm having problems with my instance variables in my tasks_controller.rb index, edit, and update actions but I'm not sure.  I've written code way more complex than this before but for some reason I'm stumbling.  It's been a while since I've written a simple app from scratch so I'm very much out of practice.

If anyone could point out the errors (or many of them) in my code, I'd appreciate it.

**Update**
Output of rake routes

```
             rails_admin        /admin                                 RailsAdmin::Engine
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#new
            user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)               devise/sessions#create
    destroy_user_session DELETE /users/sign_out(.:format)              devise/sessions#destroy
           user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#create
       new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)          devise/passwords#new
      edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)         devise/passwords#edit
                         PUT    /users/password(.:format)              devise/passwords#update
cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)                devise/registrations#cancel
       user_registration POST   /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#create
   new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)               devise/registrations#new
  edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)                  devise/registrations#edit
                         PUT    /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#update
                         DELETE /users(.:format)                       devise/registrations#destroy
                   tasks GET    /projects/:id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#index
                         POST   /projects/:id/tasks(.:format)          tasks#create
                new_task GET    /projects/:id/tasks/new(.:format)      tasks#new
               edit_task GET    /projects/:id/tasks/:id/edit(.:format) tasks#edit
                    task GET    /projects/:id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#show
                         PUT    /projects/:id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id/tasks/:id(.:format)      tasks#destroy
                projects GET    /projects(.:format)                    projects#index
                         POST   /projects(.:format)                    projects#create
             new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)                projects#new
            edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format)           projects#edit
                 project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#show
                         PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#update
                         DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)                projects#destroy
                    root        /                                      projects#index

Routes for RailsAdmin::Engine:
    dashboard GET         /                                      rails_admin/main#dashboard
        index GET|POST    /:model_name(.:format)                 rails_admin/main#index
          new GET|POST    /:model_name/new(.:format)             rails_admin/main#new
       export GET|POST    /:model_name/export(.:format)          rails_admin/main#export
  bulk_delete POST|DELETE /:model_name/bulk_delete(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_delete
history_index GET         /:model_name/history(.:format)         rails_admin/main#history_index
  bulk_action POST        /:model_name/bulk_action(.:format)     rails_admin/main#bulk_action
         show GET         /:model_name/:id(.:format)             rails_admin/main#show
         edit GET|PUT     /:model_name/:id/edit(.:format)        rails_admin/main#edit
       delete GET|DELETE  /:model_name/:id/delete(.:format)      rails_admin/main#delete
 history_show GET         /:model_name/:id/history(.:format)     rails_admin/main#history_show
  show_in_app GET         /:model_name/:id/show_in_app(.:format) rails_admin/main#show_in_app
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tasks are a nested resource under Projects

So in the edit_task_path you have to pass both the project id and the task id

```
<%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(@project, t), class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %>
```

Comment: I passed the the project and task id as you displayed above and it routes me to: http://todoapp.dev/projects/13/tasks/13/edit where the 13 is the task id.  I think my instance variables in the edit action are incorrect.  Thoughts?

Comment: Um, I dunno, @project is being set correctly in the index method... the project name is being displayed ok?  You made the change in the tasks/index.html.erb right?

Comment: I doubt it's the edit action that's the problem... you're seeing the wrong routes so that's before you get to the edit action. You said the problem is when you click edit on the index view.

Comment: Yes, the project name is being displayed ok.  And yup, I changed the tasks/index.html.erb to include: `<%= link_to "Edit", edit_task_path(@project, t), class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %></br>`

Comment: I added the output of rake routes so you could see my routes.

Comment: Even with passing the params into the edit_task_path it routes me to: http://todoapp.dev/projects/13/tasks/13/edit when I click edit.  13 is the task.id where the project.id should be 4.

Comment: Ah that was helpful! Change your routes to tale out the `member do` and the corresponding `end`... leave just the `resources :task` between the `resources :project do` and the `end`.  The named route will change... probably edit_project_task_path... use that name instead of the edit_task_path. Still pass im both @project and t.

Comment: That makes sense.  I removed the member do and changed my paths for new and edit in the task/index.html.erb.  Now I get the following `undefined method `task_path'` and better errors reports the _form.html.erb is the problem `<%= form_for(@task, :html => { :class => "well"}) do |f|  %>`

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to pass an array in the form like so: `<%= form_for([@project,@task]) do |f|  %>`  After doing that, editing all of my paths to the new routes and making sure the controller actions were looking for project_id not id as the param seems to have got it working.

Comment: Yes exactly, you got it.

Comment: It definitely put me on the right path, thank you :)  I need to be careful when setting up my routes.  Rookie mistake.  I think I'll update my question or post my own answer with the revised code in case it might help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the **edit** method on your **TasksController** is getting called and you're using the same param as an id to find both the Project and the Task. In that method you should probalby:

```
@task = Task.find(params[:id])
@project = Project.find(@task.project_id)
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, unfortunately this didn't work for me. It still routes me to http://todoapp.dev/projects/13/tasks/13/edit where 13 is the task id, it's trying to also edit the project id of 13 which doesn't exist.

Comment: Any thoughts on the instance variables?  It still routes me to todoapp.dev/projects/13/tasks/13/edit though it displays the task, the param being injected after projects is 13, not 4 like the project_id

Answer (score 0):

After some helpful input from @SteveTurczyn and @Chris Piazza I was able to get this app working.  The problem was basically an issue with the way I was setting my routes.  I wasn't nesting properly and was doing a member route inside of projects which was passing different params into my controller actions.

Here is my revised code

**routes.rb**

```
Todoapp::Application.routes.draw do

  mount RailsAdmin::Engine => '/admin', :as => 'rails_admin'

  devise_for :users

resources :projects do
  resources :tasks
end
root :to => "projects#index"
end
```

**projects_controller.rb**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @projects = Project.order('due_date ASC')
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(params[:project])

    if @project.save
        redirect_to projects_path, notice: "Project #{@project.project_name} was successfully created.".html_safe
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @project = Project.find(params[:id])

    if @project.update_attributes(params[:project])
        redirect_to projects_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end

end
```

**tasks_controller.rb**

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @tasks = @project.tasks.order("due_date ASC")
  end

  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = @project.tasks.new(params[:task])
    if @task.save
        redirect_to project_tasks_path, notice: "Task #{@task.detail} was successfully created.".html_safe
    else
        render :new
    end
  end

  def edit
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    if @task.update_attributes(params[:task])
        redirect_to project_tasks_path
    else
        render :edit
    end
  end
end
```

**view/tasks/index.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= @project.project_name %> tasks</h2>

<% @tasks.each do |t| %>
<%= t.project_id %> <%= t.id %>  <%= t.detail %> - <%= t.user.full_name %> - <%= t.due_date.try(:strftime, "%m/%d/%y") %> <%= link_to "Edit", edit_project_task_path(@project, t), class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %></br>
<% end %>

<%= link_to "Add task", new_project_task_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %><%= link_to "Projects", projects_path, class: 'btn btn-inverse btn-mini' %>
```

**view/tasks/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for([@project,@task]) do |f|  %>

  <%= f.label 'detail'%>
  <%= f.text_field :detail, :placeholder => 'Buy tool'%>
  <%= f.label 'Assigned To'%>
  <%= f.collection_select(:user_id, User.all, :id, :full_name)%>
  <%= f.label :due_date %>
  <%= f.text_field :due_date %>
   <%= f.button "Add Task", class: 'btn btn-info btn-mini', data: {disable_with: "Adding Task"} %> 

<% end %>
```

So by tweaking my routes.rb file, editing the proper paths, passing the proper params to the edit actions `(@project, t), updating my actions with the correct params that were passed by Rails, and setting an array of models in my form_for statement I got this basic app working.  Now time to add some real functionality to it.  Thanks everyone for their help.  Goes to show I need to build more apps so I don't get rusty as I have been.  I've been coding Rails for a while now and editing more complex code but for some reason when I bootstrap a new app sometimes I get brainfog and forget what I'm doing, the fundamentals that is.